# How do you add binding to ViewHolder to get the tvTodoTitle and cbDone variables of the items on the recycler view?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I was wondering how I add binding to my viewholder so I am able to get the todoTitle and cbDone variables or find an alternative way to get these variables. I have already tried researching this however, I could not put binding into the viewholder's parameters since it will only allow one (itemview: View) so if theres any alternative way to use binding or get these parameters then that will be very helpful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you need any more code then please ask.

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.todoit

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo
import com.example.todoit.data.TodoDataBase
import com.example.todoit.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var todoAdapter: TodoAdapter
    private lateinit var todoDB: TodoDataBase
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        todoAdapter = TodoAdapter(mutableListOf())

        val rvTodoItems = binding.rvTodoItems
        val btnAddTodo = binding.btnAddTodo
        val etTodoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle
        val btnDeleteTodo = binding.btnDeleteTodo

        rvTodoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        rvTodoItems.adapter = todoAdapter

        btnAddTodo.setOnClickListener {
            val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.toString()
            if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = Todo(null, todoTitle, false)
                todoAdapter.addTodo(todo)
                etTodoTitle.text.clear()
                Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully written data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

                writeData()

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "There was an error while writing data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()
            }
        }


        btnDeleteTodo.setOnClickListener {
            todoAdapter.deleteDoneTodos()
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Todo(s) Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }


    private fun writeData() {
        val todoTitle = binding.etTodoTitle.toString()

        if (todoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
            val todo = Todo(null, todoTitle, false)

            //Add data to database
            todoDB.todoDao().insertAll(todo)
        }
    }
}
```

**TodoAdapter**

```
package com.example.todoit

import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todoit.data.Todo


class TodoAdapter(
    private val todos: MutableList<Todo>,
    ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TodoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        return TodoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

    }

    fun addTodo(todo: Todo) {
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size - 1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneTodos() {
        todos.removeAll { todo ->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if(isChecked) {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        } else {
            tvTodoTitle.paintFlags = tvTodoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {


        val curTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            etTodoTitle = curTodo.title
            cbDone.isChecked = curTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, curTodo.isChecked)
            cbDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(tvTodoTitle, isChecked)
                curTodo.isChecked = !curTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample adapter, this adapter is working well. You can use it

```
public class SenListAdapter() :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SenListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
var data: MutableList<QuizResponse.Datum> = ArrayList()
var itemListener: EventListener? = null
var inflater: LayoutInflater? = null
private var onLoadMoreListener: OnLoadMoreListener? = null
var mData = ""
var context:Context?=null

constructor(context: Context, quizType: String) : this() {
    this.quizType = quizType
    this.context=context
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    return position
}

fun addAll(mData: List<QuizResponse.Datum>?) {
    data.clear();
    data.addAll(mData!!)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

fun clear() {
    data.clear()
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): SenListAdapter.MyViewHolder {
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val itemHomeSenBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<ItemHomeSenBinding>(
        inflater!!,
        R.layout.item_home_sen, parent, false
    )

    return MyViewHolder(itemHomeSenBinding)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SenListAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    populateItemRows(holder, position)
}

private fun populateItemRows(holder: SenListAdapter.MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    var item = data.get(position)

    holder.itemHomeSenBinding.tvQuizName.text = item.name
    holder.itemHomeSenBinding.tvCost.text = "₹ " + item.entryFee.toString()
    holder.itemHomeSenBinding.tvEstimatedTime.text = item.time
    holder.itemHomeSenBinding.tvWinningAmtText.text = "Win upto ₹ " + item.reward.toString()

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return data.size
}

inner class MyViewHolder(var itemHomeSenBinding: ItemHomeSenBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
        itemHomeSenBinding.root
    ) {
    init {
        setEventlistener(itemListener)
    }
}

interface EventListener {
    fun onBuyNow(position: Int, item: QuizResponse.Datum?)
    fun onStartNow(position: Int, item: QuizResponse.Datum?)
}

fun setEventlistener(onItemClick: EventListener?) {
    itemListener = onItemClick
}
}
```